After upgrade magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.7 an error in the admin grid view of my custom module appears
After upgrade magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.7 an error in the admin grid view of my custom module appears.
Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection\Interceptor::__construct(): Argument #5 ($connection) must be of type ?Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given,
my collection.php
namespace Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

   
    protected function _construct()
    {
     
        $this->_init(
        'Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\Grid',
        'Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid'
    );
    }
    
}

and my di.xml
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
  <arguments>
   <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="orderfee_grid_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">MymoduleOrderFeeGridCollection</item>
   </argument>
  </arguments>
 </type>
 <virtualType name="MymoduleOrderFeeGridCollection" type="Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">mymodule_orderfee</argument>
     <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection</argument>
   </arguments>
 </virtualType>

 <virtualType name="Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">mymodule_orderfee</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Mymodule\OrderFee\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
  <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="mymodule_orderfee_add_order_extension_fee"
          type="Mymodule\OrderFee\Plugin\OrderRepositoryPlugin" />
    </type>

Any suggestions are more than welcome.
